# Does recv() always return a complete data packet which has the expected length?

Tags: android, c, sockets, udp, rtp

I have a question regarding recv (C, Android).

Is recv guaranteed to return a complete UDP datagram when it returns?

In my case I am using recv to read RTP packets from a socket. The expected length of each RTP packet is 172 (160 bytes for payload and 12 for the header). However, I'm not sure whether I have a guarantee that I'll get the complete 172 bytes when recv returns with data.

Can anybody confirm/comment?

Comment: You will probably find this question [Does UDP allow repacketization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939796/does-udp-allow-repacketization) interesting also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per POSIX, `recv` returns the entire UDP packet, unless and error occurs or the buffer is too small for the entire packet. You can detect this by setting the `MSG_TRUNC` flag, which causes `recv` to return the frame's *actual* data length, which you can compare to the buffer size.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A UDP datagram is received intact and entire in a single recv() call, or not at all.